# ¿Como enviar información extra al mandar un formData usando fetch()?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Estoy usando este código para mandar la información de un `input` tipo `file` a mi servidor de datos

```
let formData = new FormData();
let files = document.querySelector('[type=file]').files;
formData.append('files[]', files[0]);


fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

He revisado la [documentación de fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch#Enviando_datos_JSON) para las peticiones POST, y tambien la [documentacion especifica de la propiedad body](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch#Body). En estas se indica que el body puede ser cualquiera de estos tipos de estructuras (ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, (Uint8Array y amigos), Blob/File, string, URLSearchParams, FormData) pero no dice como combinarlos.

Entonces mi pregunta es, ¿como envio un FormData y un string a la vez?

Comment: intenta agregarle directamente el  new FormData(this) y como parametro al constructor, el contexto de tu form, form ya contempla los valores de formulario, como tipo file y text. obviamente al parametro body: new FormData(this), añade la estructura de tu form

Comment: @JuanL lo que pasa es que quiero mandar otra informacion, otro string que tengo en otra parte, nada que ver con el formulario.

Comment: intenta imprimiento lo que ya se construllo con formdata, si estan los valores que quieres.

Comment: ¿Qué te impide mandar el string como parte del formData?

Comment: @PabloLozano eso es lo que no se hacer. Talvez no estoy muy familiarizado con los formData. Como lo incluyo alli? Y como lo "leo" en Php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado un objeto FormData `form`, el método [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) (que ya estás usando) se usa para añadir campos y valores:

```
form.append('miTexto', 'Texto a enviar');
```

En tu *backend* podrás leerlo de la misma manera que leas el fichero, usando el nombre que le hayas dado. Es parecido a usar un *map*.

Comment: Excelente, gracias. Yo se que esto no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta, pero en el caso de Php, esta informacion llega a la variable super global $_POST?

Comment: Debería, es equivalente a mandar un formulario con un input con ese nombre y valor.

Comment: Excelente, lo probare, gracias.